# Variable Variables usage

Tags: php, variables, post

I have this code

```
for ($a="A" ; $a<"F"; $a++){
for ($b="1" ; $b<"3"; $b++){
  $prezzo="P".$b.$a."P";
  $PXXP_NOME="$_POST['P".$b.$a."P_NOME']";
$PXXP_NOME= "${$PXXP_NOME}";
}
```

}

I can't define `$_POST['PXXP_NOME']` it doesn't work

I receive this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: $_POST['P1AP'] in ...

How can I solve it?

Comment: I'm positive you shouldn't be using variable variables.

Comment: Why is your $_POST in quotes?  Are you trying to pass it as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to do but if you want to pass the value of `$PXXP_NOME` to `$_POST[]` you shall do this: `$_POST[$PXXP_NOME];` or `$_POST[" '".$PXXP_NOME."' "];`